# Why does HTTPS break my hosts file redirection?

Tags: https, hosts

There is a machine (let's call it Machine) with a hostname in my local network. If I go to `abc.def.com`, my DNS service resolves Machine's external IP and connects me successfully with `https://`. I've added a hosts file entry so that `local.abc.def.com` resolves to Machine's local, internal IP.

However, using https://local.abc.def.com breaks everything. I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in Chrome and `This page can't be displayed` in Internet Explorer. If I replace `https://` with `http://`, it works again. What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure that your local server is serving on port 443? This might be happening because it's serving on port 80 (http), but rejecting connections on 443 (https).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, for your `abc.def.com` machine you have https redirect configured with 443 port as well.
Based on description above your application/web server you are using
is **not listening port 443** or there is a **firewall rejecting** your connection.

Comment: You are right that HTTPS is listening on port 80 but I don't understand how that would be a problem. It seems to me that any redirection should be done by the server and therefore it shouldn't matter how I refer to it (either `abc.def.com` or `local.abc.def.com`).